# Inserting a string into a Binary Search Tree C

Tags: c, string, search, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need to insert strings into a binary search tree but each run through my insert function updates all the nodes and not just the appropriate one. 
Its required that each word placed in the binary search tree has the exact amount of memory allocated for it (+1 for the NULL pointer).

Here's the struct being used:

```
typedef struct node_t{
   char *word;
   struct node_t *left, *right;
} node_t;
```

Here's how I am passing in the word:

```
for(i=0; i< original_words -1; i++)
{
    fscanf(ifp, "%s", y);
    head = insert(head, y);
}
```

And here's my insert function:

```
node_t *insert(struct node_t *head, char *word)
{

if(strcmp(head->word, word) > 0)
{

    if(head->left == NULL)
    {
        head->left = create_node(word);
    }
    else
    {
        head->left = insert(head->left, word);
    }
}

else
{
    if(head->right == NULL)
    {
        head->right = create_node(word);
    }
    else
    {
        head->right = insert(head->right, word);
    }
}

return head;

}
```

EDIT: Heres an example of the input file.

```
4
-------
bravo
-------
alpha
-------
gamma
-------
delta
```

Comment: What happens when `strcmp(head->word, word) == 0` ? You should handle that case specifically...

Comment: Something is up with inserting stuff into BSTs today. I swear to God I have seen like 5 similar questions today. Is it a BST day in some college?

Comment: @VladLazarenko You might as well be correct on this one.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it is guaranteed in the preconditions that no two words will be the same.

Comment: So every word in the input file is unique? You shoud have stated that.

Comment: Did either of the answers help you? If so, you might like to tick, upvote etc!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer (the `insert` function) assumes that `head` has already been defined on first call, it should start with the line:

```
if (head == null) return create_node(word);
```

This will also save you from the need for the null lines in the code. I'm not sure that this is *the* issue, but it is one.

Perhaps more important: how does `create_node` set up `word`? If it's something like:

```
 new_node->word = word
```

Then all you are doing is creating a collection of pointers to the word pulled out of the file. It is quite possible that each reading of a word from the file reads the word into the same piece of memory, so all you are doing is collecting a tree of pointers to the same place in memory. It should be something like:

```
 new_node->word = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
 if (new_note->word == null) {FAIL MEMORY LOSS}
 strcpy(new_node->word, word);
```